# How use special characters in a Bot Framework adaptive card

Tags: .net-core, botframework, adaptive-cards

I'm implementing a bot using Microsoft Bot Framework and need to add an adaptive card that contains especial characters.

This is a sample of my adaptive card:

```
{
  "type": "AdaptiveCard",
  "body": [
  {
    "type": "TextBlock",
    "size": "Large",
    "weight": "Bolder",
    "color": "Good",
    "text": "Satisfacción"
  },

  ...

  ],
  "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
  "version": "1.0"
}
```

Your can see the accent mark in the vowel "ó" in the word "Satisfacción".

When I use the bot in bot emuator the "ó" appears with problems:

[View error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJ8Ku.jpg)

How I can add utf8 encoding to an adaptive card?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks, 
I could solved the error saving the file with "unicode (utf-8 with signature) - Codepage 65001"

[Save as:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGxvk.jpg)

[Select Arrow:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWInz.jpg)

[Select Save with encoding:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYt6t.jpg)

[Select unicode (utf-8 with signature) - Codepage 65001](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNsOR.jpg)

thanks @Steven Kanberg for the corrections